# $ a+b+c=3.$ Prove that: $\sqrt{ab}+\sqrt{bc}+\sqrt{ca}+\frac{21}{2}\ge\frac{9}{2}\sum_{cyc}\sqrt[3]{\frac{5ab+4ac}{9}}$

Tags: inequality

> **Problem:** Let $a,b,c\ge0: a+b+c=3.$ Prove that: $$\sqrt{ab}+\sqrt{bc}+\sqrt{ca}+\frac{21}{2}\ge\frac{9}{2}\left(\sqrt[3]{\frac{5ab+4ac}{9}}+\sqrt[3]{\frac{5bc+4ba}{9}}+\sqrt[3]{\frac{5ca+4cb}{9}}\right)$$

I hope we can find a good solution for the problem. Here is my approach:

Notice: $\sqrt{ab}+\sqrt{bc}+\sqrt{ca}\le3$. Using Holder inequality for right side, we need to prove: $$\sqrt{ab}+\sqrt{bc}+\sqrt{ca}+\frac{21}{2}\ge\frac{9}{2}\sqrt[3]{9(ab+bc+ca)}$$ which is incorrect by taking accountable example.

I also tried AM-GM for RHS and the remain part is reverse, of course. Is there any mistake in my approach? Or, we need a stronger tool for this hard problem. Thanks for your time and knowledge.

Comment: Anyone help me?